# Find details of only first label from each "label category"

Tags: python

```
input = [{'label': 'Accord_row_loc', 'xmin': 48.0, 'ymin': 833.0, 'xmax': 1652.0, 'ymax': 900.3014907836914, 'likelihood': 5}, {'label': 'Accord_row_loc', 'xmin': 48.0, 'ymin': 900.30078125, 'xmax': 1652.0, 'ymax': 967.30078125, 'likelihood': 5}, {'label': 'Accord_row_loc', 'xmin': 48.0, 'ymin': 967.421875, 'xmax': 1652.0, 'ymax': 1035.0, 'likelihood': 5}, {'label': 'Accord_row_contact_info', 'xmin': 170.0, 'ymin': 1583.1669921875, 'xmax': 1651.0, 'ymax': 1617.0, 'likelihood': 5}, {'label': 'Accord_row_contact_info', 'xmin': 170.0, 'ymin': 1617.0, 'xmax': 1651.0, 'ymax': 1649.1640625, 'likelihood': 5}, {'label': 'Accord_row_contact_info', 'xmin': 170.1005859375, 'ymin': 1649.2998046875, 'xmax': 1651.0, 'ymax': 1685.0, 'likelihood': 5}, {'label': 'Accord_row_individuals', 'xmin': 48.0, 'ymin': 1801.0, 'xmax': 1652.0, 'ymax': 1867.0, 'likelihood': 5}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

Expected output = [{'label': 'Accord_row_loc', 'xmin': 48.0, 'ymin': 833.0, 'xmax': 1652.0, 'ymax': 900.3014907836914, 'likelihood': 5},{'label': 'Accord_row_contact_info', 'xmin': 170.0, 'ymin': 1583.1669921875, 'xmax': 1651.0, 'ymax': 1617.0, 'likelihood': 5}, {'label': 'Accord_row_individuals', 'xmin': 48.0, 'ymin': 1801.0, 'xmax': 1652.0, 'ymax': 1867.0, 'likelihood': 5}]
```

Got lil stuck here, please any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you detail specifically what you are trying to do, and what the error is? This code is very incomplete. What do you mean by 'first' label, and which details?

Comment: Since there are 3 different  labels , namely - "Accord_row_loc" , "Accord_row_contact_info",  "Accord_row_individuals"                                                                                                                                        input is already sorted in ascending order of "ymin". So i am looking for "index 0 "contents of these unique labels .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
def filter_by_first_label_occurence(labels):
    labels_added = []
    filtered_list = []
    for label in labels:
        if label["label"] not in labels_added:
            filtered_list.append(label)
            labels_added.append(label["label"])
    return filtered_list

label_list = [{'label': 'Accord_row_loc', 'xmin': 48.0, 'ymin': 833.0, 'xmax': 1652.0, 'ymax': 900.3014907836914, 'likelihood': 5}, {'label': 'Accord_row_loc', 'xmin': 48.0, 'ymin': 900.30078125, 'xmax': 1652.0, 'ymax': 967.30078125, 'likelihood': 5}, {'label': 'Accord_row_loc', 'xmin': 48.0, 'ymin': 967.421875, 'xmax': 1652.0, 'ymax': 1035.0, 'likelihood': 5}, {'label': 'Accord_row_contact_info', 'xmin': 170.0, 'ymin': 1583.1669921875, 'xmax': 1651.0, 'ymax': 1617.0, 'likelihood': 5}, {'label': 'Accord_row_contact_info', 'xmin': 170.0, 'ymin': 1617.0, 'xmax': 1651.0, 'ymax': 1649.1640625, 'likelihood': 5}, {'label': 'Accord_row_contact_info', 'xmin': 170.1005859375, 'ymin': 1649.2998046875, 'xmax': 1651.0, 'ymax': 1685.0, 'likelihood': 5}, {'label': 'Accord_row_individuals', 'xmin': 48.0, 'ymin': 1801.0, 'xmax': 1652.0, 'ymax': 1867.0, 'likelihood': 5}]
filtered_labels = filter_by_first_label_occurence(label_list)

print(filtered_labels)
# >>> [{'label': 'Accord_row_loc', 'xmin': 48.0, 'ymin': 833.0, 'xmax': 1652.0, 'ymax': 900.3014907836914, 'likelihood': 5}, {'label': 'Accord_row_contact_info', 'xmin': 170.0, 'ymin': 1583.1669921875, 'xmax': 1651.0, 'ymax': 1617.0, 'likelihood': 5}, {'label': 'Accord_row_individuals', 'xmin': 48.0, 'ymin': 1801.0, 'xmax': 1652.0, 'ymax': 1867.0, 'likelihood': 5}]
```

Hopefully I understood your question properly.

Explaination: It remembers which labels you have added with the `labels_added` list. Then, if the label you are checking now is not `in` the list, it adds it to both `labels_added` and the output `filtered_list`. Hope this makes sense